# When did the referenced conversation take place?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Near the end of WoT Book 13 "[**Towers of Midnight**](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Towers_of_Midnight)", Mat & Thom are conversing with

> Moiraine, bringing her up to speed on events that occurred during her captivity.

There we see the following exchange between her and Mat:

> "Elayne is Queen, then?"
>
> "Sure is. Her mother was killed by Rahvin," Mat said.
>
> "So you told me."
>
> "I did? When?"
>
> "A lifetime ago, Matrim," she replied, smiling.

Given that she "died" prior to Rand attacking Caemlyn, **what conversation is she referring to?**

---

***Note:*** The preferred answer would include the chapter and page where it occurred, but honestly I'm just trying to sort out in my mind what in the world she's talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in Fires of Heaven, chapter 51 "News Comes to Cairhien". Page 611 in the edition I have.

> "What news?" Rand said sharply, "News Elayne shouldn't hear?"
>
> Mat looked up at Moiraine. "You mean there's something you haven't ferreted out?"
>
> "What news, Mat?" Rand demanded.
>
> "Morgase is dead"

The conversation continues to explain it was Gaebril according to the rumors Mat heard, but Rand corrects him that Gaebril is Rahvin.

Moiraine is present for the whole conversation.